# Include parent element in pug / jade

Tags: html, pug

On my website the main content in each page needs to be a child of a container div. I am trying to place this div in a header which is included on every page, however when rendered the div closes itself and does not have the main content as its child.

Here is my pug for an example page:

```
html
    body
        include includes/header.pug
            div(id='main-content')
                [main content goes here]
```

Here is my pug for the header include:

```
 nav
    [navigation bar goes here]
 div(id='container')
```

When I render this page, in place of the main content being a child of the container div, the code `<div id='container'></div>` appears at the end of the code. When I removed the tabulation before `div(id='main-content')`, the code `<div id='container'></div>` appears just before the main content. I want to avoid having to hard-code the container div on every page.

Answer (score 0):

Pug `include` statements don't accept blocks or child elements. Instead, you should make use of [template inheritance](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html). This let's you define content common to many pages in one place, and allows you to define slots where page-specific content should go as blocks.

Using your example content, one approach would be to set up the following files:

> **_wrapper.pug:** (the main template each page will extend)
>
> ```
> html
>   head
>   body
>     include _header
>     #main-content
>       .container
>         block content
> ```
>
> **_header.pug:** (a partial that contains your navigation)
>
> ```
> nav#navigation
>   .container
>     ul
>       li
>         a(href='#') home
>       li
>         a(href='#') contact
> ```
>
> **homepage.pug:** (a homepage that extends the wrapper template)
>
> ```
> extends _wrapper
>
> append content
>   h1 This is your homepage
>   p Lorem ipsum
> ```
>
> **contact.pug:** (a contact page that extends the wrapper template)
>
> ```
> extends _wrapper
>
> append content
>   h1 This is your contact page
>   p Lorem ipsum
> ```

When compiled, this will render two HTML files with the common content reused:

> **homepage.html**
>
> ```
> <html>
>   <head></head>
>   <body>
>     <nav id="navigation">
>       <div class="container">
>         <ul>
>           <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
>         </ul>
>       </div>
>     </nav>
>     <div id="main-content">
>       <div class="container">
>         <h1>This is your homepage</h1>
>         <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> **contact.html**
>
> ```
> <html>
>   <head></head>
>   <body>
>     <nav id="navigation">
>       <div class="container">
>         <ul>
>           <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
>         </ul>
>       </div>
>     </nav>
>     <div id="main-content">
>       <div class="container">
>         <h1>This is your contact page</h1>
>         <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

Hope this is helpful.